# Redux selector function triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Code Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-colden-3browz?file=/src/App.js

I just get started with Redux, and I have a slice defined in `src/store/sizeSlice.js`, and my redux store is in `src/store/store.js`. Now the idea is when the two buttons (`addCol`, `addRow`) get clicked, they will dispatch actions to increment the global states of the number of rows and columns. I use two `useSelector` hooks in `App.js`.

Now whenever I click one of the two buttons, there will be four outputs to the console. For example, if I click `addRow`, there will always be one console log of `selectRow`, and three logs of `selectCol`. I know that the `useSelector` gets called when the function component, in this case `App.js` rerenders. There should only be two outputs (one `selectRow`, and one `selectCol`), but why is the selector function getting called three times? Especially the button that is related to it (dispatch `addCol` action in this case) didn't get clicked?

Comment: I generally wouldn't worry about this too much. The latest react version started calling function components twice when mounting iirc. It's not necessarily an indication that something is wrong.

Comment: @timotgl Just FYI, this hasn't anything to do with double-mounting a component, or any of the other effects associated with the `React.StrictMode` component, since OP isn't using `React.StrictMode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React can, and will, on occasion "render" the app more than once ***during the "Render Phase"*** to compute a diff that should be rendered, *i.e. flushed*, to the DOM ***during the "Commit Phase"***. The "Commit Phase" is what we generally consider to be a React component "rendering", because this is when we see the UI update.

[image]

Why is this distinction important?

Note that the *entire* React Function component body is the "render" method, and the "render" method is called during the "Render Phase" which "may be paused, aborted, or restarted by React". This means React may call the "render" method as many times as it needs to in order to compute a diff during the reconciliation process, i.e. when state updates have been enqueued and are processed.

You are console logging as an *unintentional side-effect* in the `useSelector` hook callback.

These logs ***should not be*** confused for the component rerendering or being rendered to the DOM multiple times. The logs are unintentional side-effects of the "Render Phase" which can occur several times.

If you care to log state updates ***as a result of state update -> render to DOM*** then move all console logs into a `useEffect` hook. The `useEffect` hook is for running *intentional* side-effects. 1 React component render == 1 intentional side-effect.

App example:

```
function App() {
  const col = useSelector(selectCol);
  const row = useSelector(selectRow);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Count:", { col, row });
  }, [col, row]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Row />
      <Addcolumn />
      <Addrow />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit redux-selector-function-triggered-multiple-times]